# Data structure in C# (3.0) that represents a CUBE

Tags: c#-3.0

Can you please give me some idea about how to design a data structure in C# (3.0) which will give a representation of 3D data structure.

I mean to say something similar to cube. Like stock data to be viewed based on time , location .

Kindly give a simple working example or even a link will do.

Comment: umm, a 3 dimensional array?  

var t = new int[10,10,10];

Comment: @Thinking You are not thinking outside the box!

Comment: You aren't providing enough information...a dimension is simply an attribute; by that definition, any object with three properties is a three-dimensional data structure.

Comment: @David: no one thinks outside the box - some of us just have bigger boxes. :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis ooooh, profound... I like to think in sheds rather then boxes though to be fair.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Good one. I dislike the whole "outside-the-box" thing.

Comment: @AMissico: I guess that makes you "pro-cubist". :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Hypercube man. Hypercube!

Answer (score 6):

I doubt this is what you're looking for, but since a CUBE has three identical dimensions it can be represented with a single integer.

```
int CUBE = 4; // A 4x4x4 cube
```

Stock data has more than three dimensions (if you must call them that) and each is unique.

Is this homework?

Comment: I don't think so...judging by his other questions, it doesn't look like he asks homework questions.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
struct StockTickData
{
    string Symbol;
    decimal Price;
    DateTime When;
    string Where;
}
```

I'm not sure you really need "3D" here.

Comment: @Adam: not if you're 0-based. :)

Answer (score 0):

erm, well taking your question to mean one thing, I would suggest something like

```
class cube{
  private size;
  public set_size(value){
    if (value < 0){
      value = -value; // makes sure we have a positive size
    }
    this.size = value
  }
  public get_size(){
    return this.size;
  }
  public get_volume()
  {
    return this.size*this.size*this.size
  }
}
```

But you may also mean a 3D array... which is an array of arrays of arrays

Of top of my head, you might have the inner most array having three elements, representing an x,y,z value of a vertex. You would then have an array of these vertex arrays, lets say three again, which would be triangles. Then you have an array of these triangles to make an object.

Though here is a situation where object orientated programming will make it simpler to develop. Make a vertex class with thee integers and functions to control the single vertex. Then make a triangle class which has three 'vertex' properties and functions to control the triangle, such as rotating around one vertex. Then another class for an object that can have an array of triangles.

Let me know if you want me to expand or clarify any of this

Comment: You really do that sort of thing to your co-workers? Quietly changing a passed parameter to some other value?

Comment: I see your point. But genrally, that is what documentation is for. Would you just start using a function with out knowing what to pass it or what the function even does? Secondly, with OOP a class is meant to keep it's data sensible, so in this instance, not allowing negative length makes sense, after all, you try drawing a cube who's sides are -1 meter long. Sorry if I sound a bit argumentative, it's just my view on the way these sort of things should be done. I am in favour of the 'explained black box' ie, you don't 'know' how a class works, but you have been told how to expect it to work.

Comment: You're certainly correct; a negative size shouldn't be allowed. That's what exceptions are for.

Comment: If you must do something like this consider using Math.Abs() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your cube needs following properties:

1) Location coordinate which is most likely vector of 3 floats describing XYZ coordinates.
2) Dimensions of your Cube, again vector of 3 floats describing height width and depth of cube
3) Orientation of your Cube, again vector of 3 floats describing yaw pitch and roll angles

Basically a 3x3 matrix is enough to represent cube.

[X Y Z]
[L W D]
[Y P R]

These 3 vectors are the minimum and sufficient to describe a cube in 3D space, and perform various operations on it. Operations like rotation, stretching, moving are performed using matrices. DirectX/Direct3D documentation has lots of info this kind of stuff, if this is what are you looking for. Also any basic 3D gamedev book will do.